# Timeout-Setting for Stateful Session Bean?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

For my JavaScript web application the backend is a JBoss application server.
The JavaScript frontend contacts ALWAYS ONE servlet (front controller).
The servlet makes ONE lookup (plus "narrow") at login time.
This lookup is a lookup for a SFSB (Stateful Session Bean).
The result from this lookup is stored in an HttpSession object.
All subsequent communication between servlet and SFSB is made by this
stored remote object.

The session timeout (for a HttpSession object) from JBossWeb (Tomcat) is 30 minutes.
So every time, when there is NO activity on the frontend (> 30 minutes), the
session expires, the session with everything in it - also the remote interface
of the SFSB - is deleted.

In the meantime the SFSB is passivated to disk
(deploy/ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml -> idleTimeoutSeconds=300).

The default timeout for my SFSB is infinite (removalTimeoutSeconds=0). So the default is that no passivated sfsb is automatically removed.

Is there actually any reason to not set the SFSB timeout (removalTimeoutSeconds) to 30 minutes (30*60) in my case (same as session timeout)?

Answer (score 0):

The only exception will be long running background transactional processes associated with the stateful bean. If it takes longer than specified duration to complete, then will result in exception probably transaction not active.

Therefore, even if the there is timeout at front-end, the background process needs to finish. In such case, removal timeout may affect the processing & needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: This is if you use the new feature of asynchronous methods. Otherwise the Servlet response won't be sent until it finishes the task.

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu A container shouldn't passivate a stateful bean if its having extended persistence context, which is the case with most of the stateful session beans & long running background processes which are independent of front-end activities.

Comment: Background processes means asynchronous. It doesn't matter if you have extended or transactional persistence context. Persistence context is just a set of references, no executions.

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu No, it isn't necessary that background processes must be asynchronous. I have faced several instances where the user has to wait, displaying progress bar, till the process completes. In this case, session may time-out, but the process needs to continue its operation.

Comment: Well this is not background process :) maybe just from the client's point of view. And is not a request/response, it's an ajax if you have a progress bar, otherwise you see just the waiting cursor until the 'process' finishes and the response is sent back.

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu May be I should give other example. If user initiates a process, like file upload which runs in background & then continues with other activities, it isn't a background process.